# #import Directive in C

Tags: c, visual-c++, com

What would be an alternative for Microsoft C++ compiler's `#import` directive in a C (*not* C++) source code?

Are there any tools which automatically produce C interfaces from a given type library?

Comment: Writing COM code in C is cruel and usual punishment, outlawed by the Geneva convention on human rights.  Just don't, write these bits of your program in C++.

Comment: You can `#import` once, and then grab produced files `.tl*` files into your C code, possibly with respective edit for C builability (being covered by Geneva convention, I did not have a chance to check out if these headers are C friendly).

Comment: @Hans: That may be true, but, since the WHO has banned C++ from the list of health-safe programming languages, I still would prefer to have my brain unimpaired :) I will consider your remark nonetheless. @Roman: This is not possible; `.tl*` files are not only C unfriendly, but also C++ exclusive.

Comment: Well, this Geneva convention applies equally to COM server authors.  Surely the WHO rule also bans C++ from code that you depend on.  Nice of COM to make this completely invisible, but you'd better check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I know is using the OLE/COM object viewer (OLEVIEW.EXE) to get part of the IDL back, correcting a few missing things, and then running that through MIDL again.